# Value does not update in if statement, discord python

Tags: discord.py

The code works normally when there is only one option for:
if food == 'apple':

However, when I add 'apple' or 'straw'-
whenever the choice of food lands on 'meat' or 'pasta', the serving size instead uses the serving sizes for 'apple' or 'straw' instead of the ones for 'meat' or 'pasta'

I am unsure how to go about this. I want multiple options of food along with their serving sizes.

```
        options = ('straw', 'meat', 'apple', 'pasta')
        status = ('Skinny', 'Average', 'Plump')
        food = random.choice(options)
        statusr = random.choice(status)

           if food == 'apple' or 'straw':
                if statusr == "Skinny":
                    servingr = 'This can feed 0 people'
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="You get a **{} {}!**\n*Serving: {}*".format(statusr, food, servingr), color=0xE69138)
                    embed.set_footer(text="Press {} to add this to the pile! Otherwise, press {}".format(check, fail))
                    sendy = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    await sendy.add_reaction(check)
                    await sendy.add_reaction(fail)  
                elif statusr == "Average":
                    servingr = 'This can feed 0 people'
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="You get a **{} {}!**\n*Serving: {}*".format(statusr, food, servingr), color=0xE69138)
                    embed.set_footer(text="Press {} to add this to the pile! Otherwise, press {}".format(check, fail))
                    sendy = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    await sendy.add_reaction(check)
                    await sendy.add_reaction(fail)  
                elif statusr == "Plump":
                    servingr = 'This can feed 0 people'
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="You get a **{} {}!**\n*Serving: {}*".format(statusr, food, servingr), color=0xE69138)
                    embed.set_footer(text="Press {} to add this to the pile! Otherwise, press {}".format(check, fail))
                    sendy = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    await sendy.add_reaction(check)
                    await sendy.add_reaction(fail)  
            elif food == 'meat' or 'pasta':
                if statusr == "Skinny":
                    servingr = 'This can feed 1 people'
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="You get a **{} {}!**\n*Serving: {}*".format(statusr, food, servingr), color=0xE69138)
                    embed.set_footer(text="Press {} to add this to the pile! Otherwise, press {}".format(check, fail))
                    sendy = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    await sendy.add_reaction(check)
                    await sendy.add_reaction(fail)  
                elif statusr == "Average":   
                    servingr = 'This can feed 2 people'
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="You get a **{} {}!**\n*Serving: {}*".format(statusr, food, servingr), color=0xE69138)
                    embed.set_footer(text="Press {} to add this to the pile! Otherwise, press {}".format(check, fail))
                    sendy = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    await sendy.add_reaction(check)
                    await sendy.add_reaction(fail)  
                elif statusr == "Plump":
                    servingr = 'This can feed 4 people'               
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="You get a **{} {}!**\n*Serving: {}*".format(statusr, food, servingr), color=0xE69138)
                    embed.set_footer(text="Press {} to add this to the pile! Otherwise, press {}".format(check, fail))
                    sendy = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                    await sendy.add_reaction(check)
                    await sendy.add_reaction(fail)                
            reaction, author = await self.bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=reactioncheck)
            if reaction.emoji == (check):
                with open("list.json", "r") as f:
                    data = json.load(f)
                try:
                    today = date.today()
                    item2 = ("{} {} {} {}/{}".format(statusr, food, servingr, today.month, today.day))
                    data[itemlist].append(item2)
                except KeyError:
                    data[itemlist] = [item2]
                with open("list.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(data, f)
                    await ctx.send("Succesfully added '{}' to the list '{}'".format(food, itemlist))
            if reaction.emoji == (fail):
                await ctx.send("Not added.")
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem; what were you expecting what is happening?

Comment: You use `servinglist` in the meat code area but it is not defined anywhere, what is it? Also, your possible options for `statusr` are `('small', 'Skinny', 'Average')`, but you check for `'small'`, `'medium'` and `'big'` in your `if` blocks.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code. That was a previous iteration when trying to solve the issue. 

The issue is, I want different serving sizes to show up for the different foods, and add them to the list.

For example, apple:
small (feeds 1 people)
medium(feeds 1 people)
and meat:
small (feeds 5 people)
medium (feeds 5 people)

However, when the embed is called and meat is selected, it uses the serving sizes of apple.

Answer (score 0):

your size can either be one of these: ('small', 'Skinny', 'Average'),
but you check for 'small', 'medium' and 'big', so there is that mistake. Also, the way you are describing your problem:

> It works fine for the first food, which is apple. If it is small, it adds "this can feed 4 people!"

This also isn't correct, right? Please check again and maybe edit your question

Edit:

```
try:
    today = date.today()
    item2 = ("{} {} {} {}/{}".format(statusr, food, servingr, today.month, today.day))
    data[itemlist].append(item2)
```

This will also always fail right? Because servingr is out of the scope here, it can only be accessed from inside your if-statements

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code. That was a previous iteration when trying to solve the issue. 

The issue is, I want different serving sizes to show up for the different foods, and add them to the list.

For example, apple:
small (feeds 1 people)
medium(feeds 1 people)
and meat:
small (feeds 5 people)
medium (feeds 5 people)

However, when the embed is called and meat is selected, it uses the serving sizes of apple.

Comment: I don't know, your description again makes no sense, it is not at all what is happening in the code. However, I see other mistakes I think. Your variable servingr cannot be accessed outsite of the scope of your if's. maybe create the variable under fail = ..., so servingr = ""

Comment: Sorry, I actually updated it again to me way more clear. I figured out the cause.
The issue is, when I use or statements, the serving sizes use the very first ones.
if food == 'apple' or 'straw'
serving = '[Feeds 2 people!]'
if food == 'meat' or 'pasta'
serving = '[Feeds 3 people!]'

When meat or pasta is chosen, it uses the serving value of apple and straw.